# Determination of the number of binary strings of length m and Hamming weight r, which can contain consecutive zeros up to k

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinatorics

I have a little problem in MatLab.

I am trying to compute the number of binary words of length m with a given Hamming weight r, which only contain up to k consecutive zeros. The Hamming weight is the number of non-zero entries in the binary word.

I implemented following code based on the paper ["Constant-Weight and Constant-Charge Binary Run-Length Limited Codes" (Kurmaev)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.4246).

```
%% Different cases for the weight r
if (r==0)
    if (m<=k)
        numberOfBinaryStrings = 1;
    else
        numberOfBinaryStrings = 0;
    end
else

%% Computation of the number of binary strings
% Determination of the sum bound
bound = min(m,k);

d = k+1;
tmp = 0;

for j=0:bound
    for s=0:r-1
        if (m-j-1-s*d < r-1)
            bin1 = 0;
        else
            bin1 = nchoosek(m-j-1-s*d,r-1);
        end

        if (m-j-1-(k+1)-s*d < r-1)
            bin2 = 0;
        else
            bin2 = nchoosek(m-j-1-(k+1)-s*d,r-1);
        end

        tmp = tmp + (-1)^s * nchoosek(r-1,s) * ( bin1 - bin2 );
    end
end
numberOfBinaryStrings = tmp;
```

end

The code is working well for a given k and low word length and Hamming weights r. At some parameters, especially large parameters, I get negative results, which should not be. 
I already tried to replace the nchoosek functions by gammaln-function to avoid overflow. But there I also get negative results.

Do you have any idea, what I could do? Thank You!

Comment: What are typical values of `m` and `r`? Can you explicitly generate all words and check now many fulfill the condition?

Comment: 'm' can be everything greater zero and 'r' can be everything between zero and 'm'. For example 'm=7','r=4' and the words can contain up to 'k=2' consecutive zeros. In [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306756/number-of-binary-and-constant-weight-strings-of-length-m-which-do-not-contain-k) all words are listed at the end of the very last comment.

Comment: @N.Younger: It would be helpful if you included actual parameters which lead to an incorrect value. (See the how-to-ask section on constructing a [mcve]). But FWIW, I think the second line should be `d=bound+1` instead of `d=k+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic to get arbitrary size integers in Matlab.  This should remove any possible overflow issues.

If that does not solve your problem, then you have a logic error somewhere.  In that case I would suggest producing another solution, and trying to produce a minimal example that differs.  Then try to figure out why.

Here is another solution in Python that you can use for comparison.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

stored_word_counts = {}

def word_counts(word_length, ones, max_zero_run):
    if 0 == ones:
        if max_zero_run < word_length:
            # Impossible.
            return 0
        else:
            # String of all zeros.
            return 1
    key = (word_length, ones, max_zero_run)
    if key not in stored_word_counts:
        # We will try all places we can put a 1.
        mid = (ones+1)/2 # Cut in half, round up.
        ones_before = mid - 1
        ones_after = ones - mid
        stored_word_counts[key] = sum(
                word_counts(pos, ones_before, max_zero_run) * word_counts(word_length - pos - 1, ones_after, max_zero_run)
                    for pos in xrange(ones_before, word_length - ones_after)
                )
    return stored_word_counts[key]

print(word_counts(50, 20, 5)) # Change this line as needed.
```

Comment: I tried to use the vpi function. It really works now. It is really slow for large numbers, but it works.

Comment: @N.Younger I'm glad it works.  The python one is almost certainly faster.  Like 4 seconds to produce a 300 digit answer for words of length 1000.

Answer (score 0):

For `m` small enough you can:

1. Generate all binary words of length `m` as a matrix with each words in a row. This can be easily done via [conversion to binary](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html).
2. Keep only those with weight `r`. The weight of each word can be obtained by [summing](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) the above matrix along the second dimension.
3. Count how many words to not have `k+1` consecutive zeros. Those words can be detected by observing the output by [2D-convolution](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) of the negated words with a vector of `k+1` ones.

Code:

```
m = 7;
r = 4;
k = 2;
h = dec2bin(0:2^m-1) - '0'; % step 1
h = h(sum(h,2)==r, :); % step 2
result = sum(all(conv2(1-h, ones(1,k+1), 'valid') < k+1, 2)); % step 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not interested in the words, I am just interested in the number of these words and m can grow very large. For small m, the code is working.